# Lightbox working offline but not online

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox, offline

My lightbox gallery is working perfectly offline but i've just uploaded it online at it's not working at all, clicking on images just takes you to a new page.

Here is the page ... www.jevonz.co.uk/portfolio.html

The file paths seem to be fine and I've even switched from locally hosting jquery to using the google hosted one but all to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated. Cheers!

Here's the code for the page if that gives any more info.

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="Jevonz.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="jquery-lightbox-0.5/css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" rel="stylesheet"   type="text/css">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-lightbox-0.5/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js">      </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
<div id="LayoutDiv1" align="center">
  <img src="images/JevonzHeader.jpg"/>
</div><!-- end LayoutDiv1 -->

<div id="Navigation" align="center">
  <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
</div> 
  <!-- end Navigation -->




 <div id="galleria" align="center">

  <a href="images/gallery/bio.JPG" rel="lightbox" title="Bio Luminesence"><img src="images/gallery/Thumbnails/bio_thumb.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Bioluminescence" /></a>
  <a href="images/gallery/blueRobotLarge.jpg" rel="lightbox"><img src="images/gallery/Thumbnails/blueRobot_thumb.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="" /></a>
  <a href="images/gallery/DeepSea.JPG" rel="lightbox"><img src="images/gallery/Thumbnails/DeepSea_thumb.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="" /></a>
  <a href="images/gallery/DiD.JPG" rel="lightbox"><img src="images/gallery/Thumbnails/DiD_thumb.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="" /></a>
  <a href="images/gallery/EscapeLife.JPG" rel="lightbox"><img src="images/gallery/Thumbnails/EscapeLife_thumb.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="" /></a>
  <a href="images/gallery/GorillaLarge.jpg" rel="lightbox"><img src="images/gallery/Thumbnails/GorillaLarge_thumb.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="" /></a>
  <a href="images/gallery/LifeRobot.jpg" rel="lightbox"><img src="images/gallery/Thumbnails/LifeRobot_thumb.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="" /></a>
  <a href="images/gallery/LureDeep.jpg" rel="lightbox"><img src="images/gallery/Thumbnails/LureDeep_thumb.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="" /></a>
  <a href="images/gallery/TangledFamily.JPG" rel="lightbox"><img src="images/gallery/Thumbnails/TangledFamily_thumb.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="" /></a>
  <a href="images/gallery/WorldBelow.JPG" rel="lightbox"><img src="images/gallery/Thumbnails/WorldBelow_thumb.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="" /></a>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
// Use this example, or...
$('a[@rel*=lightbox]').lightBox(); // Select all links that contains lightbox in the  attribute rel

});
</script>



 </div>


</div> 
<!-- end gridContainer -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting 403 Forbidden errors on the lightbox files, I have posted a screenshot of the Net panel in firebug:

http://cl.ly/image/2m461v012M1i

Check the permissions on that folder and make sure that the webserver can read that folder and its contents.

Comment: I've just changed the permissions, still no luck though.

Comment: Figured it..

$('a[@rel*=lightbox]').lightBox();

The '@' is no longer needed.. i removed this and hey presto is works!